# SQL Query for Grouping the results based on sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID  Seq  Amt
1   1    500
1   2    500
1   3    500
1   5    500
2   10   600
2   11   600
3   1    700
3   3    700
```

I want to group the continuous sequence numbers into a single row like this:

```
ID  Start  End  TotalAmt
1   1      3    1500
1   5      5    500
2   10     11   1200
3   1      1    700
3   3      3    700
```

Please help to achieve this result.

Comment: which version of sql server? is (id+seq) unique?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT
    ID, Seq, Amt,
    SeqGroup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Seq) - Seq
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Start = MIN(Seq),
  [End] = MAX(Seq),
  TotalAmt = SUM(Amt)
FROM numbered
GROUP BY ID, SeqGroup
ORDER BY ID, Start
;
```

Comment: +1 Took me a while to figure out the `- Seq` trick and verify (for myself) there can't be any collisions but OP can't ask for any better than this.

Comment: +1 I had a suspicion that ROW_NUMBER (or RANK,...) would help but abandoned it for my (more complicated and probably slower) solution.

Comment: @Lieven: Please believe me when I'm saying that with a praise like this one doesn't need any formal upvoting. :) Thanks, you are very kind! By the way, you shouldn't have deleted your answer. One more recursive CTE demonstration is never too many, in my opinion, as that is a rather tricky technique, which is best learnt by examples. Also I didn't notice any Martin's or Quassnoi's presence here. :)

Comment: @Andriy, I've deleted mine to avoid future embarassement :). *...I didn't notice...* I'll just have to add you to my list for future reference.

Comment: @Andriy, @Lieven - undoubtedly a good solution. Would be funny for OP to come back with sql2000. I posted another option

Comment: @Lieven: What an honour, thanks for the warning. :) I'll just have to remember to upvote your reasonable answers *before* posting mine if any (just in case), in the hope you wouldn't dare delete them as easily.

Comment: @Andriy: I already have table with data. Plealse modify the same query to select from the existing table instead of using UNION ALL. Please help

Comment: @Nagesh: There. Removed the sample data CTE, but you still have to replace `atable` with the actual table name. By the way, a correct answer doesn't have to fit your actual environment *literally*. As long as it is basically a solution to your problem, you are free to accept it as *the* solution.

Comment: That is an elegant and beautiful solution. Excellent.

Comment: I need to select ranges based on some condition like `((MAX(Seq)-MIN(Seq)+1)/10)>0` Is it possible?

Comment: @SanthoshNayak: That can make a good question. Feel free to submit one, I'm sure there'll be some suggestions.

Comment: @AndriyM Got solution. made second query as inner query. and used `PARTITION BY` instead of `GROUP BY` and put my condition for outer query.

Comment: @SanthoshNayak: Came to the same solution in my mind myself. You could still post *and* [self-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) that question. Self-answering is encouraged here, you know. (Well, it certainly is if the question and the answer are laid out well, anyway.) It's no pressure, just keep that option in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work nicely. `@breakingRows` will contain all rows that break the sequence of `id` and `seq` (i.e. if `id` changes or if `seq` is not 1 more than the previous `seq`). With that table you can select all rows of such a sequence within `@temp`. I must add however that performance will probably be not all that good because of all the subqueries but you'll need to test to be sure.

```
declare @temp table (id int, seq int, amt int)
insert into @temp select 1, 1, 500
insert into @temp select 1, 2, 500
insert into @temp select 1, 3, 500
insert into @temp select 1, 5, 500
insert into @temp select 2, 10, 600
insert into @temp select 2, 11, 600
insert into @temp select 3, 1, 700
insert into @temp select 3, 3, 700

declare @breakingRows table (ctr int identity(1,1), id int, seq int)

insert into @breakingRows(id, seq)
select id, seq
from @temp t1 
where not exists 
    (select 1 from @temp t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.seq - 1 = t2.seq)
order by id, seq

select br.id, br.seq as start, 
       isnull ((select top 1 seq from @temp t2 
               where id < (select id from @breakingRows br2 where br.ctr = br2.ctr - 1) or 
                     (id = (select id from @breakingRows br2 where br.ctr = br2.ctr - 1) and
                      seq < (select seq from @breakingRows br2 where br.ctr = br2.ctr - 1))          
               order by id desc, seq desc),
               br.seq)
      as [end],
      (select SUM(amt) from @temp t1 where t1.id = br.id and 
        t1.seq < 
            isnull((select seq from @breakingRows br2 where br.ctr = br2.ctr - 1 and br.id = br2.id), 
                   (select max(seq) + 1 from @temp)) and 
        t1.seq >= br.seq)
from @breakingRows br
order by id, seq
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The solution is perfectly working! But I can mark only one answer as Best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's perhaps a more elegant way to do this (something hints at me that there is), but here's an approach that will work if you're using a version of SQL Server that accepts common table expressions:

```
use Tempdb
go

create table [Test]
(
    [id] int not null,
    [Seq] int not null,
    [Amt] int not null
)

insert into [Test] values
(1, 1, 500),
(1, 2, 500),
(1, 3, 500),
(1, 5, 500),
(2, 10, 600),
(2, 11, 600),
(3, 1, 700),
(3, 3, 700)

;with
lower_bound as (
    select *
      from Test
     where not exists (
        select *
          from Test as t1
         where t1.id = Test.id and t1.Seq = Test.Seq - 1
    )
),
upper_bound as (
    select *
      from Test
     where not exists (
        select *
          from Test as t1
         where t1.id = Test.id and t1.Seq = Test.Seq + 1
    )
),
bounds as (
    select id, (select MAX(seq) from lower_bound where lower_bound.id = upper_bound.id and lower_bound.Seq <= upper_bound.Seq) as LBound, Seq as Ubound
      from upper_bound
)
select Test.id, LBound As [Start], UBound As [End], SUM(Amt) As TotalAmt
  from Test
  join bounds
    on Test.id = bounds.id
   and Test.Seq between bounds.LBound and bounds.Ubound
 group by Test.id, LBound, UBound

drop table [Test]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. Your solution is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since Andriy has already posted the gold solution, here's my take using an UPDATE statement to get the result from a temp table, just for fun.

```
declare @tmp table (
    id int, seq int, amt money, start int, this int, total money,
    primary key clustered(id, seq))
;
insert @tmp
select *, start=seq, this=seq, total=convert(money,amt)
from btable
;
declare @id int, @seq int, @start int, @amt money
update @tmp
set 
    @amt = total = case when id = @id and seq = @seq+1 then @amt+total else amt end,
    @start = start = case when id = @id and seq = @seq+1 then @start else seq end,
    @seq = this = seq,
    @id = id = id
from @tmp
option (maxdop 1)
;
select id, start, max(this) [end], max(total) total
from @tmp
group by id, start
order by id, start
```

Notes:

- **btable**: your table name
- **id int, seq int, amt money**: expected columns in your table

Comment: It works, but that's some new SQL Server stuff to me. You've managed to post something valueable just by having fun, thanks. :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the ´option (maxdop 1)´ ? EDIT : I think I just figured it out. You update ´@tmp´ with data from ´@tmp´ itself. Multithreading would interfere with that, correct ?

Comment: @Sem Yes, because this is a brittle query. There is no way to use ORDER BY in an UPDATE query, so AFAIK this should work - but no guarantees - if we cluster in the order required, and force maxdop 1. **I stress again** (and voted too), Andriy's answer is the gold one.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

```
select id, min(seq), max(seq), sum(amt) from table group by id
```

OOps, sorry, it is wrong query as you need sequence

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, MIN(Seq) as Start, MAX(Seq) as End, SUM(Amount) as Total
FROM ( 
        SELECT t.*, Seq - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Seq) Rn
        FROM [Table] t
    ) as T
GROUP BY Id, Rn
ORDER BY Id, MIN(Seq)
```