# SQL need to return ranges from a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, range, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that has an integer column named ID with values that may have gaps (e.g. 1,2,3,4,7,8,10,14,15,16,20)

I would like to find a query that would, in the example above, result in this:

1-4
7-8
10
14-16
20

**= UPDATE =**

Thanks to the code below (which seems to work well in SQL Server), I feel I am very close to getting this to work in MS-Access which is the goal.  I'm still getting a syntax error though in my statment which I can't figure out...

SELECT val FROM
(

```
SELECT islands.PORTID, CSTR(islands.PORTID ) as val 
FROM MYTABLE islands
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = islands.PORTID - 1)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = islands.PORTID + 1)

UNION 


SELECT 
    rngStart.PORTID
    ,CSTR(rngStart.PORTID ) + '-' 
        + CSTR(MIN(rngEnd.PORTID)) as val
FROM MYTABLE rngStart 
INNER JOIN MYTABLE checkNext ON checkNext.PORTID = rngStart.PORTID + 1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PORTID 
    FROM MYTABLE tblRangeEnd 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = tblRangeEnd.PORTID + 1)
) rngEnd on rngEnd.PORTID > rngStart.PORTID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = rngStart.PORTID - 1)
GROUP BY rngStart.PORTID
```

) as tbl
ORDER BY PORTID ASC

Comment: Sql Server? postgreSQL? Oracle? syntax may differ so it would be useful to know the right syntax.

Comment: Ultimately I need to be able to support SQL Server, Oracle, and Access.  Unfortunately, MS-Access is most important.

Comment: @user1069916: See my edit for how to make this work in Access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query for Grouping the results based on sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087864/sql-query-for-grouping-the-results-based-on-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT val FROM
(
    -- Get the islands
    SELECT islands.ID, CAST(islands.ID as varchar(10)) as val 
    FROM @t1 islands
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = islands.ID - 1)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = islands.ID + 1)

    UNION 
    
    -- Get the ranges
    SELECT 
        rngStart.ID
        ,CAST(rngStart.ID as varchar(10)) + '-' 
            + CAST(MIN(rngEnd.ID) as varchar(10)) as val
    FROM @t1 rngStart 
    INNER JOIN @t1 checkNext ON checkNext.ID = rngStart.ID + 1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM @t1 tblRangeEnd 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = tblRangeEnd.ID + 1)
    ) rngEnd on rngEnd.ID > rngStart.ID 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t2 WHERE t2.ID = rngStart.ID - 1)
    GROUP BY rngStart.ID
) as tbl
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I used a table variable called @t1 but just replace that with your table name.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119406/) it is in action.

### EDIT

To make this work in Access you will have to change the joins a little bit. Try this:

```
SELECT val FROM
(
    SELECT islands.PORTID, CSTR(islands.PORTID) as val 
    FROM MYTABLE islands
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = islands.PORTID - 1)
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = islands.PORTID + 1)

    UNION 

    SELECT 
         rngStart.PORTID
        ,CSTR(rngStart.PORTID) + '-' + CSTR(MIN(endPORTID)) as val
    FROM MYTABLE rngStart 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT checkNext.PORTID as nextPORTID, rngEnd.PORTID as endPORTID
        FROM MYTABLE checkNext
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT rngEnd.PORTID
            FROM MYTABLE rngEnd 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = rngEnd.PORTID + 1)
        ) AS rngEnd on rngEnd.PORTID > checkNext.PORTID - 1
    ) AS checkNext ON checkNext.nextPORTID = rngStart.PORTID + 1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE t2 WHERE t2.PORTID = rngStart.PORTID - 1)
    GROUP BY rngStart.PORTID
) as tbl
ORDER BY PORTID ASC
```

Comment: That is simply awesome.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```
SELECT
    MIN(i), MAX(i)
FROM (
    select 
        i - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl t WHERE t.i < tbl.i) g,
        i 
    from tbl
) t
GROUP BY g
```

It'll be slow for sure, but I don't see other way to number rows in access.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #sequence (id int not null primary KEY)

insert into #sequence(id)
    select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 10
    union all select 14
    union all select 15
    union all select 16
    union all select 20


--Find Contig ranges
select l.id as start,
    (
        select min(a.id) as id
        from #sequence as a
            left outer join #sequence as b on a.id = b.id - 1
        where b.id is null
            and a.id >= l.id
    ) AS fend
from #sequence as l
    left outer join #sequence as r on r.id = l.id - 1
where r.id is null;

--Find missing values in sequence
select l.id + 1 as start, min(fr.id) - 1 as stop
from #sequence as l
    left outer join #sequence as r on l.id = r.id - 1
    left outer join #sequence as fr on l.id < fr.id
where r.id is null and fr.id is not null
group by l.id, r.id;

drop table #sequence
```

This will give you both the ranges and the gaps between the ranges so you can see what you have or what you need. sample data provided

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you access to function `row_number()`.

```
with C as
(
  select ID,
         ID - row_number() over(order by ID) as grp
  from YourTable
)
select min(ID) as MinID,
       max(ID) as MaxID
from C
group by grp
```

or with a sub-query instead of a common table expression.

```
select min(ID) as MinID,
       max(ID) as MaxID
from (select ID,
             ID - row_number() over(order by ID) as grp
      from YourTable) as C
group by grp
```

Result:

```
MinID       MaxID
----------- -----------
1           4
7           8
10          10
14          16
20          20
```

Try it on SQL Server https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119411/