# Merging data in a single SQL table without a Cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate, database-cursor

I have a table with an ID column and another column with a number. One ID can have multiple numbers. For example

```
ID | Number
 1 |  25
 1 |  26
 1 |  30
 1 |  24
 2 |  4
 2 |  8
 2 |  5
```

Now based of this data, in a new table, I want to have this

```
ID | Low | High 
1  |  24 |  26
1  |  30 |  30
2  |  4  |  5
2  |  8  |  8
```

As you can see, I want to merge any data where the numbers are consecutive, like 24, 25, 26. So now the low was 24, the high was 26, and then 30 is still a separate range. I am dealing with large amounts of data, so I would prefer to not use a cursor for performance sake (which is what I was previously doing, and was slowing things down quite a bit)...What is the best way to achieve this? I'm no SQL pro, so I'm not sure if there is a function available that could make this easier, or what the fastest way to accomplish this would be.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Almost the same: [SQL Query for Grouping the results based on sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087864/sql-query-for-grouping-the-results-based-on-sequence).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The key observation is that a sequence of numbers minus another sequence is a constant.  We can generate another sequence using `row_number`.  This identifies all the groups:

```
select id, MIN(number) as low, MAX(number) as high
from (select t.*,
             (number - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by number) ) as groupnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, groupnum
```

The rest is just aggregation.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with CTE and recursion:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT T.ID, T.NUMBER, T.NUMBER AS GRP
  FROM T 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID AND T.NUMBER -1 = T2.NUMBER 
  WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
  UNION  ALL
  SELECT T.ID, T.NUMBER, GRP
  FROM CTE 
  INNER JOIN T
  ON T.ID = CTE.ID AND T.NUMBER  = CTE.NUMBER + 1
)
SELECT ID, MAX( NUMBER ), MIN(NUMBER)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID, GRP
```

[Results at fiddlesql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5832/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `WHILE` loop structure with a **table variable** instead of the cursor.

For example,

```
DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE
(
    MyID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [ID] int,
    [Number] int
)

DECLARE @Count int, @Max int

INSERT INTO @TableVariable (ID, Number)
SELECT ID, Number
FROM YourSourceTable

SELECT @Count = 1, @Max = MAX(MyID)
FROM @TableVariable

WHILE @Count <= @Max
BEGIN

    ...do your processing here...


    SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```

Comment: What?  No; loops in SQL are almost always the wrong thing to do.  SQL was designed with set logic in mind, and implementations will usually be most performant when written to take advantage of this.  I also have a feeling this sort of `WHILE` loop will use some of the same underlying processes as a cursor, which would leave you in just as bad a spot as before.  Besides which, you haven't shown the necessary conditions to reset `@Count`...

Comment: In conjunction with a table variable there've been a lot of cases where the performance gains have been well worth it. `@Count` in this case wouldn't need to be reset, just incremented as each record in the table variable is processed, though that might change depending on OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Number] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Number])
VALUES
    (1, 25),
    (1, 26),
    (1, 30),
    (1, 24),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 8),
    (2, 5)
;

    select ID, 
           MIN(Number)
         ,(SELECT MIN(Number) 
                  FROM (SELECT TOP 2 Number from Table1 WHERE ID =
                  T1.Id ORDER BY Number DESC) as DT)
    from Table1 as T1
    GROUP BY ID
    UNION 
    SELECT ID, MAX(Number), MAX(Number)
    FROM Table1 as T1
    GROUP BY ID;
```

[Live Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/89d22/6)