# SQL Query needed to get result in TWO columns grouped by TYPE and PERCENTAGE) in MySQL by joining more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, percentage, pie-chart

in MySql database I have to make some little tricky query.
I must get result only in TWO COLUMNS (TYPE (PROJECT,SUPPORT,EDUCATION) and VALUE (60 and 40 on example))

I have static table which contains types:

```
T1

ID  TYPE
1   PROJECT
2   PROJECT
3   PROJECT
4   SUPPORT
5   EDUCATION
```

I have static table T2 with all tasks that has value of some of the type:

```
    T2

  TASK    T1ID

    1      1
    2      1
    3      2
    4      3 
    5      4
    6      5
```

T3 is DYNAMIC table of created tasks with some IDS.

```
T3 

ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

T4 table has information who created those tasks.

```
T4

T3ID     Name
1       Bob Marley
2       Bob Marley
3       Bob Marley
4       Bob Marley
5       Tom Cruise
6       Bob Marley
```

and finally T5 contains info from  T2 and T3

```
T5

TASK    T3ID
  1       1
  2       2
  3       3
  5       4
  1       5
  5       6
```

For some specific person (always one person- in this example Bob Marley or Tom Cruise)
I must haave statistics in PERCENTAGE how many they worked on PROJECTS or SUPPORT or EDUCATION.

So I will select Bob Marley- his T3ID is 1,2,3,4 and 6.

In table 5 his tasks ID are are 1,2,3,5 and again 5.

So when I look in table T2 his T1 IDs are 1,1,2,4 and 4.
It means that Bob Marley worked on 3 PROJECTS and 2 SUPPORT Tasks.

So when I select Bob Marley result should be:

```
PROJECT  60
SUPPORT  40
```

This is the final result from query.
How can I achieve this? 
I know that it must be a couple of JOIN statements and of course you can use in WHERE clause

```
where name='Bob Marley'
```

If I put

```
 `where name=Tom Cruise
```

result should be

```
PROJECT 100`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  t4.Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'PROJECT'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) Project,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'SUPPORT'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) SUPPORT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'EDUCATION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) Education
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = t2.T1ID
INNER JOIN t5 ON t2.task = t5.task
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t5.t3id
INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.Id = t4.t3id
GROUP BY t4.Name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25097/4)

This will give you:

```
|       NAME | PROJECT | SUPPORT | EDUCATION |
----------------------------------------------
| Bob Marley |      60 |      40 |         0 |
| Tom Cruise |     100 |       0 |         0 |
```

for the sample data you posted.

**Note that:** This will give you only the `Name` that was involved in projects and tasks. You might need to `OUTER JOIN(LEFT or RIGHT)` the table instead of `INNER JOIN` to include those `Name`s that were not involved in any tasks or projects (the unmatched rows), with `IFNULL()` to replaces `NULL`s with zeros.

---

### Update:

You can use the `CONCAT()` function to do this, but it will be easier and more readable if you include the previous query inside a subquery and do this in an outer query like so:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  CONCAT(CAST(project   AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), ' AND ', 
         CAST(support   AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), ' AND ', 
         CAST(education AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS Percentage
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    t4.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'PROJECT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) Project,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'SUPPORT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) SUPPORT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.type = 'EDUCATION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(t1.type) Education
  FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = t2.T1ID
  INNER JOIN t5 ON t2.task = t5.task
  INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t5.t3id
  INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.Id = t4.t3id
  GROUP BY t4.Name
) t;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25097/8)

This will give you:

```
|       NAME |               PERCENTAGE |
-----------------------------------------
| Bob Marley | 60.00 AND 40.00 AND 0.00 |
| Tom Cruise | 100.00 AND 0.00 AND 0.00 |
```

You can add the `WHERE` clause to limit this values to only any user name like `WHERE Name = 'Some name'` in the outer query or in the subquery.

---

### Update 2

OK, Sorry I missed that. There is no need to `PIVOT` or `CONCAT()` or dynamic SQL to do so. You can do this like so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.type,
  COUNT(t2.task) * 100 / 
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM T4 t 
   WHERE t4.Name = t.Name) AS Percentage
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = t2.T1ID
INNER JOIN t5 ON t2.task = t5.task
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t5.t3id
INNER JOIN t4 ON t3.Id = t4.t3id
WHERE t4.Name = 'Bob Marley' 
GROUP BY t4.Name, t1.type;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25097/22)

This will give you:

```
|    TYPE | PERCENTAGE |
------------------------
| PROJECT |         60 |
| SUPPORT |         40 |
```

Comment: Hi thank you for response but I MUST get result onlyh in TWO COLUMNS. Because I am using it in some report for PIE CHART and query MUST give result in two columns. Like in example I give- in one column PROJECT and SUPPORT and in OTHER value- 60 AND 40. Colud you please modify your query to give such result? Thank you

Comment: Please sorry maybe I did not explain very well but I must have in two columns. So somewhere in WHERE CLAUSE you can PUT name of specific person from T4 table (on example where name='Bob Marley')

Comment: I also must include education because there can be MANY values in T1 and T2 table (this is just example). They are static that means they are not changeable but they have many different rows this is just my little example. So please do not mention specificly values from T1 or T2 table. Thank you a lot

Comment: Please just do not enter PROJECT,EDUCATION or SUPPORT somewhere in QUERY. There are many different types and rows in T1 table- it must be calculated from SQL Query although that table is not changeable so often but maybe one day it will be changed (added with some more different types). Thank you a lot

Comment: Result should be without 'AND'  PROJECT 60 SUPPORT 40 for Bob Marley  his name should not be in result

Comment: Name I give as parameter so you can just put in your SQL query WHERE NAME='Bob Marley'. I will changed it my self for Tom Cruise.  And sorry please it should not be concatantion with 'AND'.

Comment: I will explain you know clearly: I have two columns. In fiorst column is type - on example PROJECT and in other column is PERCENTAGE value on example 60. Below is the name of other type on example SUPPORT and in other column is value 40. PLEASE look at my example for result in my original question that is how result should look like- only with those two columns. Thank you and sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: @Stefke OK Sorry, So you need only two columns column is the value `support` or `project` and the other is the percentage?

Comment: Example of result is exactly below my sentance: "So when I select Bob Marley result should be:" in my original post.

Comment: Yes exactly. But just to keep in mind that PROJECT and SUPPORT are just examples and there are many more values from T1 table so please do not hard code that in your query. You can hard code only name in query (where name='Bob Marley') I will change it later my self. Thank you really for your time

Comment: Query should dynamicalyy check all types and show them for that specific person. So for Bob Marley it will show PROJECT and SUPPORT, for Tom Cruies it will show only PROJECT and 100%, for some third person it will show on example TRAVEL 50%, ADMINISTRATION 50% and so on. I am just changing the name of person for which I must get statistics

Comment: @MahmoudGamal `+1` for these efforts and GUESS WHAT! [I found the query that I was literally hauanting you for.. It belongs to Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125297/merging-data-in-a-single-sql-table-without-a-cursor) ;) Check that out, I am sure you have seen it before.