# SQL Count Grouping by a sequence of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sequence, gaps-and-islands

i have a SQL table like this:

```
id      pNum
-----   --------
100     12
100     13
100     15
100     16
100     17
200     18
200     19
300     20
300     21
300     25
```

and i want to group by the id and the pNum sequences, and count the number of rows. having a result like this.

```
id      res
-----   --------
100     2
100     3
200     2
300     2
300     1
```

any idea on how to do it?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: what res does represent in the grouped table

Comment: Micorsoft SQL -----------------

Comment: Oh, you're grouping "res" as continuous sequences, right?

Comment: res is the count of id grouped by sequences of pnum

Comment: nick is right, grouping by continuous sequences

Comment: smells of recursion; and of homework ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DBMS supports window functions (e.g. SQL Server 2005+)

```
SELECT id,
       count(*) AS res
FROM   (SELECT *,
               [pNum] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [pNum]) AS Grp
        FROM   YourTable) T
GROUP  BY id,
          Grp
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75270/2)

Comment: @user2051336 - This type of requirement is often known as finding "gaps and islands". The approach in my answer is attributed to Itzik Ben Gan AFAIK. What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @MartinSmith - This one might also be useful for MS SQL server http://stackoverflow.com/a/4324654/247184

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087864/sql-query-for-grouping-the-results-based-on-sequence):

```
declare @table table
(
    id int
    , pnum int
)


insert into @table
values (100,    12)
, (100,     13)
, (100,     15)
, (100,     16)
, (100,     17)
, (200,     18)
, (200,     19)
, (300,     20)
, (300,     21)
, (300,     25)

;WITH numbered AS (
  SELECT
    ID, pnum,
    SeqGroup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY pnum) - pnum
  FROM @table
)
SELECT
  ID,
  COUNT(*) AS res
FROM numbered
GROUP BY ID, SeqGroup
ORDER BY id, MIN(pnum)
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `row_number() - pnum`. What does this assignement thing `SeqGroup = ` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - As I suspect you are probably aware it is a SQL Server specific way of aliasing columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith: not really. Is there a difference to the `as foo` standard syntax?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Not really. Some people (such as Aaron Bertrand) prefer it as it is easier to lime up the column aliases. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)